# Php: DateTime: how to set only seconds (not hours neither minutes)

Tags: php, datetime

I have a code where I have to "round" to the lowest minute.

- `16:05:00` should become `16:05:00`
- `16:05:01` should become `16:05:00`
- `16:05:29` should become `16:05:00`
- `16:05:30` should become `16:05:00`
- `16:05:31` should become `16:05:00`
- `16:05:59` should become `16:05:00`

I want to use the DateTime object.
There are no functions such as:

- `setHours()`
- `setMinutes()`
- `setSeconds()`

Here's the beginning of my code:

```
$my_date=DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'Y-m-d H:i:s',
    $bd_date
);  
$my_date->setTimezone(self::$TimeZone);
```

Now I'd like to set the "seconds" part to zero.

Do you have an elegant way of only setting minutes the way I'd like to?

Nota: I'm not looking for a solution like "divide by getTime() by 60, convert to integer, then multiply by 60". I'm looking for a generic solution to set the seconds, not only to "0".

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Is [setTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php) elegant?

```
$my_date->setTime ( $my_date->format("H"), $my_date->format("i"), $new_second_val );
$my_date->setTime ( $my_date->format("H"), $new_minute_val, $new_second_val );
// etc...
```

Comment: it is THE most efficient way to SET hours and minutes on a DateTime object. Also, `format` is the only documented way to extract hours from a DateTime.

Comment: NO, it is not elegant. Carbon is elegant. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Ok. Carbon, however, is not in the PHP standard library, so while it may be more elegant, it's not quite what OP asked for.

Comment: The OP never said that the third party libraries is off limit for the project. And it was provocative of you to ask "Is it elegant?", when it is obviously not. Don't get me wrong, I like your solution, it is really good for cripple projects, where no third party libraries are allowed.

Comment: `I want to use the DateTime object.`

Comment: Note: if you have `declare(strict_types=1)` , you need to add an explicit cast to int , i.e `(int) $my_date->format("H")` etc.

Comment: @allan.simon The answer was written way before `(int)` was a thing ;)

Comment: @wroniasty yes , my comment was more for the guy in 2020 (i.e me) who will see this answer and wonder why it throws an exception.

Comment: not so elegent, but its readable and worked solution ! really !

Answer (score 12):

Just set the seconds to "00"

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_paulo');
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:00');
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work... returns false instead of an object.

Comment: This doesn't work, if you use createFromFormat(), since the given value is 2017-02-15 15:10:20 . So the seconds aren't parsed and causing function not to return a DateTime object

Answer (score 3):

Best way to set the second/minute or hour by simply using the second/minute or hour function on Carbon DateTime Object. (obvious you will need to create carbon object)

```
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->hour(2)->minute(20)->second(0);
```

Comment: When I read that (even though it's perfect and good Php code) I'm so glad I've given up on Php 3 years ago `;^)`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a late answer but it might help someone the way it helped me.

You can add the first line if you need a specific timezone

`date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Johannesburg');
 $created = date('Y-m-d H:i:00', time());`

Answer (score 0):

from docs should be

```
$dt = Carbon::create(2012, 1, 31, 15, 32, 45);
echo $dt->startOfMinute(); // 2012-01-31 15:32:00
```